# ember.js ember generate acceptance-test does not generate a test file

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to learn ember by following the tutorial that they have on their website.

One of the section was about generating a test file by running `ember generate acceptance-test super-rentals` which is supposed to generate a file under `tests/acceptance/` and show this in the terminal

```
$ ember generate acceptance-test super-rentals
installing acceptance-test
  create tests/acceptance/super-rentals-test.js
```

However, when I run the command it only shows:

```
% ember g acceptance-test super-rentals
installing acceptance-test
```

And it does not create any files under the tests folder.

I can't seem to find anything relate to this on stack overflow.

Does anyone know why this is not working?

Comment: What version of Ember CLI are you using? You could find out by running `ember version`.

Comment: i was using 4.4

Answer (score 1):

there was a regression in ember 4.4 recently -- the fix hasn't been released yet, so you'll need to downgrade ember-source to `~4.3.0`

Here is the reported issue(s):

- https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/20081
- https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/20088

And the fixing PR: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/20082